# How to render SectionList with Nested looped of Objects in data

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have the below json structure

```
{
  "title": "Name(s)",
  "type": "Text",
  "data": [
    {
      "source": "DB",
      "title": "All",
      "list": [
        {
          "name": "ABCD",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "BCDE",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "CDEF",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "DEFG",
          "count": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "EFGH",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Category(s)",
  "type": "Text",
  "data": [
    {
      "source": "DB",
      "title": "All",
      "list": [
        {
          "name": "Vegetables",
          "count": 1942
        },
        {
          "name": "Saloon",
          "count": 355
        },
        {
          "name": "General Store",
          "count": 331
        },
        {
          "name": "Restaurants",
          "count": 130
        },
        {
          "name": "Fast Food",
          "count": 108
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to show the data as Like

1st SectionHeader : "Name(s)"
1stRow:               "ABCD"
2ndRow                "BCDE"
3rdRow                "CDEF"
.
.
.

2nd SectionHeader : "Category(s)"
1stRow:               "Vegetables"
2ndRow                "Saloon"
3rdRow                "General Store"
.
.
.
Here, should I use SectionList/Flatlist/ Mix both of them to get the above result.

In flatlist/sectionlist I am getting the section header Names(s)& Category(s) in renderSectionHeader but in renderItem, 
How Can I loop the "list" array of objects.
Kindly let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the data like the following,

eg:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Name(s)",
    "type": "Text",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "ABCD",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "BCDE",
        "count": 1
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Category(s)",
    "type": "Text",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Vegetables",
        "count": 1942
      },
      {
        "name": "Saloon",
        "count": 355
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
...
]
```

And use `SectionList` for display it,

eg:

```
 ...
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item.name}</Text>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      sections={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    />
    ...
```